# I can't access my settings from sublime plugin

Tags: python, settings, sublimetext2

I'm trying to write a plugin to sublime text 2 and now i need to access the settings values. However I can't seem to figure out how to do that exactly. I've even copied code from other plugins and still cant manage to access my settings values.

This is how it looks right now:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SendMailCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def run(self, edit):
        settings = {}
        settings["use_tls"] = self.view.settings().get("smtp_tls", None)
        settings["use_port"] = self.view.settings().get('smtp_port', 25)

        print settings
```

Needless to say none of these settings have another value than the default. My PackageName.sublime-settings file looks like this:

```
{
    "smtp_server": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "smtp_tls": true,
    "smtp_port":587
}
```

If I change the name of the setting to point to something in the general user settings file, then it works so I'm guessing that either I have the wrong name for my settings file or I'm just doing it wrong for accessing `plugin local` settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so actually it is really simple, however I've seem to have missed that to load in the settings for your own project you must do the following:

```
settings = sublime.load_settings("<project-filename>.sublime-settings")
```